# How to run flutter in chrome with args in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

How can I run my flutter app in chrome with args?

I want to run/debug/attach my flutter app in a chrome session with `--disable-web-security`.

In the end I would expect to have a single launch configuration that does launch my app in a single chrome session (similar to `flutter run -d chrome`).

In the `launch.json`, I did play around with attach/launch, compounds, tasks but could not make it work.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Launch D1",
            "configurations": [
                "Launch Chrome",
                "app1"
            ],
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app1",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--disable-web-security",
                "--user-data-dir=%APPDATA%\\..\\Local\\tempc"
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "app1",
            "cwd": "app1",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "chrome"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: where did you get `runtimeArgs` from? i dont see it here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes

Comment: Its part of the chrome 'type' (best guess). You basically have attributes that are shared for all 'types' + parameter that each 'type' implements. The setting above does work for me, but i end up with two chrome sessions.

Comment: @PeterPakre did you solved it?

Comment: @marco.marinangeli No, but I solved it for me using browser extensions or running the application as an app on the phone. Both do work for me well enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having certificate issues running on web, you can disable the warnings using `"runtimeArgs": ["--ignore-certificate-errors"]`

You can also follow other workarounds mentioned on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46904).

Comment: Thread really helps (: